# Debugging with gdb - Weird info

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures

when I try to debug the generated core file, it doesn't show where is the problem, normally it displays a function (or other) but this time it only shows "??":

```
> gcc -g -W HashTable_SeparateChaining.c -o HashTable_SeparateChaining
> ulimit -c unlimited
> ./HashTable_SeparateChaining

    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

> gdb HashTable_SeparateChaining core

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from HashTable_SeparateChaining...

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 25151]
Core was generated by `./HashTable_SeparateChaining'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00005645bbb023a1 in ?? ()
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

P.S: I'm on Ubuntu.

Edit: When I then proceed to type "layout next" and then "run" this appears:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555553ad in insert (H=0x5555555592a0, key=0x55555555601e "name1",
    value=0x555555556018 "David") at HashTable_SeparateChaining.c:87
```

So, what happened at the beginning?

Comment: Do you know whether the executable was built with debugging symbols? `-g` if using `gcc`.

Comment: @kaylum I compiled it like this: `gcc -g -W file.c -o file`

Comment: How are you running `gdb`? Please add that to the post as well. This looks suspicious: `warning: core file may not match specified executable file.`

Comment: @kaylum Sorry, done.

Comment: But the log you have shown does not show it producing any core. It is not clear whether you have just left it out of the log or whether it is indeed that you have recompiled the program and have loaded an old core. Please show a complete and exact log.

Comment: It sounds like you're entering a library of syscall that doesn't have debugging symbols or you've jumped to somewhere in memory you shouldn't have

Comment: @kaylum oook, done!

Comment: Most likely, your program had ruined the stack. That is, some function returns to nobody knows where (causing a segfault), and `gdb` is baffled.